# How to get the internal names of GUI programs?

Tags: gui

I want to find out what is the internal name of a graphical program.

I know that `ps aux` or `top` can be used, but is there a way to find out without console, using the mouse?

Maybe an app I can start and then click on a window to see it's application name?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250757/is-there-a-linux-command-to-determine-the-window-ids-associated-with-a-given-pro

Answer (score 8):

I didn't find a tool without console, but there are some console tools: `xwininfo` and `xprop`

You can start a console and type

```
xprop|grep WM_CLASS
```

click on the desired window and you get for example

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox"
```

some programs already have the program name in that output, for example:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "muon", "Muon"  
or   
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "xfce4-taskmanager", "Xfce4-taskmanager"
```

If not, then use `xwininfo` to search for that name:

```
xwininfo -root -children|grep Firefox
```

you get a list of all processes, and some of them contain the program name "firefox"

> ```
>  0x1424f98 "Firefox": ("firefox" "Firefox")  1x1+-100+-100  +-100+-100
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Open the `System Monitor` application (which is `gnome-system-monitor`).

or `Task Manager` (which is `xfce4-taskmanager` on Xubuntu)